# Disabling Connection Pooling in Rails to use PgBouncer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgbouncer

We have a Ruby on Rails 4.2.8 project that accesses a large PostgreSQL database.  We are going to add a new server for connection pooling using PgBouncer.

Since PgBouncer will handle the db connection pooling, would we need to turn off Rails automatic connection pooling?  We do not have anything configured in our database.yml, so I would think that the default (Pool) of 5 is being used.

1. Does the addition of PgBouncer mean we should turn off Rails
   connection pooling?
2. If so, how does that work, do we just set Pool
   to 0 in the database.yml?

Thank you

Comment: what did you guys end up doing?

Answer (score 7):

TLDR; don't change anything

The pooling in rails is different than the pooling in PGBouncer. The rails connection pool is a group of connections available to any thread within that process, usually just 1. Each connection in your rails pool will have a connection to your postgres database, or PGBouncer if that's sitting in front of postgres. In a large rails app, you'll run multiple rails processes on every server and multiple servers behind a load balancer. Something like this:

[image: pooling architecture]

Without PGBouncer, every connection to postgres creates a new postgres process. At scale you'll want to limit the number of postgres processes that run so you don't max out CPU and memory. PGBouncer pools connections from all of your rails pools across all processes and all servers, and efficiently switches between them.

Comment: There is good reason to disable connection pooling, rails 5 doesn't work well with pgbouncer transaction pooling, and the long lived connections that the connection pool in rails uses, don't work well with pgbouncer session pooling because in session pooling 1 client connection maps to 1 server connection.

So without disabling the rails connection pool to get short lived connections, we can't have more threads in rails than my postgres db has connections.

Comment: @FrederikBaetens makes a very valid point. We got hit with PgBouncer not respecting some database.yml settings like statement_timeout since SET/RESET is not supported in transaction pooling.
Have you tried this out Frederik?  (or anyone else .. ?)
I would think it would introduce some latency in the Rails application since it now needs to create a TCP connection (assuming PgBouncer is on a separate machine) for every request that needs the DB.

Comment: I haven't looked into setting things like statement_timeouts, but all we had to do to get transaction pooling to work correctly is [disabling advisory locks and disabling prepared statements](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database).

Afaik transaction pooling doesn't need to set up a new connection every time. The connections between pgbouncer and the DB server, are persistent. The connections from your client to pgbouncer are also persistent since the rails connection pool keeps connections to pgbouncer in the pool open at all times.

Comment: Ideally rails would do some form of transaction or statement pooling by itself, with some sort of database actor, rather than a 1 connection per thread model.

Comment: For future reference, afaik disabling connection pooling in rails isn't possible although it would sometimes be more convenient to have new short lived db connections per request without connection pooling. But this isn't a problem since pgbouncer transaction pooling + the changed settings mentioned above resolve most problems.